# How to stretch inline frame size in panel stretch layout in ADF?

Tags: frame, inline, oracle-adf

I have .jsff page that contain command button and inline frame. What I want to do is, I want to make command button remain static at the same place and only inline frame can move when scroll the page.

Currently what I do is I set some panel stretch `layout(StyleClass:AFStetchWidth)`. I put the command button at the top. Inline frame in scroll panel group at the center.

Here is my structure:

af:panelStetchLayout(StyleClass:AFStretchWidth)
>

Panel Stretch Layout facets

```
  bottom
  center
     af:panelGroupLayout-scroll
          af:inlineFrame     (StyleClass:AFStretchWidth)
  end
  start
  top
    af:panelGroupLayout-horizontal
         af:commandButton-back
```

When I run this page: command button remain static at the top. This is correct, but the size of the inline frame is small. Is there a way to make an inline frame to be stretch?

Comment: have you got any solution for this?

Comment: I wonder if `panelStetchLayout` is misspelled, and should be `panelStretchLayout`. In any case, the formatting here is rather confusing, and I don't think there is any value in keeping this question open.

Answer (score 0):

set the (StyleClass:AFStretchWidth) on the af:panelGroupLayout-scroll.

Comment: HI...Thanks for the reply..width for the inline frame is stretch but what about the height?If can, I dont want to set the height(in px)because if user screen is small,they can see the browser scroll bar.If like that command button will be not static anymore.I want to set the height that always fit to user screen.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting this attribute :

sizing="preferred"

I have used it and it works pretty well inside panel stretch layout.

Answer (score 0):

just i solve it as following:

```
    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" halign="center">
    <af:inlineFrame id="if1" source="/index.html" styleClass="AFStretchWidth" inlineStyle="height:100%;"/>
</af:panelGroupLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

inlineStyle="height:100%;"
on default af:panelGroupLayout 
thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue. Here I have solved it as below:

I have used panel splitter for inline frame.

```
     <af:panelSplitter styleClass="AFStretchWidth" inlineStyle="height:500px;" id="ps3" dimensionsFrom="parent"
                         positionedFromEnd="false">
        <f:facet name="first">
         <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl11" >
           <af:inlineFrame styleClass="AFStretchWidth" partialTriggers="cb3" source="#{pdfHandler.servletString}"
                           id="if1" visible="true" binding="#{pdfHandler.inLineFrame}" shortDesc=" "
                           inlineStyle="height:500px;"/>
          </af:panelGroupLayout>
         </f:facet>
```

Here as shown above,

```
  I have added inlineStyle for height in both panelSplitter and in inlineFrame.
  Added dimensionFrom for panelSplitter as 'parent'
  Surround inlineFrame with panelGroupLayout.
```

With this, It worked for me.