# Oracle ADF inline Frame stretching issue

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am working on inline frame and passing HTTP Servlet URL Pattern as a source to inline frame which read the images from drive and displays it.

The issue is with the image it is not stretching to full height width and height  available.

1. i tried every solution try handling it from css Height:100vh; width:100%;
2. surronding the inline frame with panel group scroll and giving it AFStretchWidth.
3. I also try this [How to stretch inline frame size in panel stretch layout in ADF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374571/how-to-stretch-inline-frame-size-in-panel-stretch-layout-in-adf)

but nothing helped me.
I m using Inline Frame inside Panel Stretch and refreshing images on Poll.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the af:inlineframe at the center facet of an 
https://docs.oracle.com/html/E12419_09/tagdoc/af_panelStretchLayout.html